# Symfony - checkboxtype

Tags: symfony, checkbox

i have problem with checkboxtype in symfony framework. My code for creation form is:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add('table_records', CheckboxType::class)
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'delete'))
            ->getForm();
```

My problem is array in checkbox, because i need checkboxname for example table_records[], for many checkboxes.

Comment: Are you sure, `CheckboxType` is the correct one to use here instead of [`ChoiceType`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#select-tag-checkboxes-or-radio-buttons)?

Comment: Do you have a TableRecord entity... ?

Comment: I need to result form, which render symfony was: <form><input type="checkbox" name="table_records[]" value="val1"><input type="checkbox" name="table_records[]" value="val2"><input type="checkbox" name="table_records[]" value="val3"></form>

Answer (score 5):

Use a ChoiceType with and set `expanded` to `true`.

```
$builder->add('table_records', ChoiceType::class, array(
    'choices' => array(),
    'expanded' => true
))
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, using ChoiceType is the right way to do this.

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('table_records', ChoiceType::class, array())
        ->add('save', array('label' => 'delete'))
        ->getForm();
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question it not clear if you need:

**1.** Group of Multiple Checkbox , will not be named as you ask

**2.** Collection of Checkbox , each will be named with a index number

**1.**
Result example:

```
<form> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="table_records[]" value="1"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="table_records[]" value="2"/>
    ...
</form>
```

You need:

```
    ->add('table_records',ChoiceType::class,[
        'multiple'=>true,
        'expanded'=>true,
        'choices'=>[
            'label1'=>'value1',
            'label2'=>'value2'
        ]
    ])
```

Look at `multiple` + `expanded` both are true and this will make the ChoiceType render Checkbox inside the form.

**2.** Result Example:

```
<form> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="table_records[0]" value="1"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="table_records[1]" value="2"/>
    ...
</form>
```

Then you need:

```php
->add('table_records',CollectionType::class,[
    'entry_type'=>CheckboxType::class,
    'entry_options'=>[ //Options for CheckboxType goes here
        '...'
    ]
])
```